# Unexpectedly deleted SQL File Stream Shared location

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, sqlfilestream

I unexpected delete SQL File Stream Shared location, is there a way to restore the Shared location. When i try to open SQL File table from SSMS Explore File Table Directory it works on Server, but it doesn't allow to open from client machine. I already enabled Remote Access for SQL File Shared. Is there a way to restore back.

Also can any one suggest me unable to open File Explorer from SSMS. it shows unauthrised access

Comment: This should be moved to dba